# BroadcastReceiver in android == Eventlistener ins as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, event-listener

is a BroadcastReceiver who recives an Intent (android) the same as an Eventlisterner who recives a DispatchEvent (actionscript3)?

Answer (score 0):

In the sense that it is an event handling mechanism, simple answer: yes. Sources:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-ii-intent-receivers/

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html